# Reverse rows of n*n matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I have a matrix `[[1 2 3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`
How can I reverse it horizontally so it become `[[3 2 1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7]]`

Comment: Have you tried iterating through the outer `List`, and for each element (in this case, the inner `List`), apply a way to reverse? This way the scope of the problem becomes simpler -- how to make `[1, 2, 3]` as `[3, 2, 1]`, and repeat from first element of the outer List to the last.

Answer (score 5):

If `a` is your matrix (represented as in your question), the following will flip it horizontally:

```
map(list.reverse, a)
```

This will change it in place. If you'd rather create a new matrix:

```
b = [row[::-1] for row in a]
```

If you deal with matrices a lot, I'd recommend that you take a look at [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/). It has a lot of numerical primitives and is very widely used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension as follows:

```
m = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

print([list(reversed(x)) for x in m])
```

Output:

```
[[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
l= [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

# take each list in the list of lists l and reverse that in-place
for item in l:
    item.reverse()

print(l)
```

output:

```
[[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7]]
```

This is in-place conversion, so no need to create any temporary variables to store values in the inter-mediate steps.